# How to create a container storing functions with different signatures?

Tags: c++, std-function

I implemented a class which depended on an interface for sending data.
Concrete versions of the interface were implemented for testing and for production and they were injected at construction (depending if the class was being tested or used in production)

This works but there is a maintainence overhead on maintaining multiple overloaded send functions that do very similiar things.

I would like to template the send function however that is impossible on an overriden function.

My next idea is rather than the class depending on an interface, it will contain a map of datatypes to callbacks. This means I can specify the functionality for each datatype and inject it into the class depending on if I want test functionality or real functionality.

The difficulty comes because the map has to store functions with different signatures because the paramter type is different for every function.

How best can I do this? Is the idea sound or is there a better design?

Comment: You can’t mix functions with different signatures in a compiled language like C++. I think the easiest way is to create a common base class for the callbacks and let subclasses hold the differences. Then you can make a map of the base class objects. Anyway, you should [edit] your question to show relevant code.

Comment: starting from paragraph 2 your quesiton is very unclear. Why is it a maintanance problem? Of course you would not repeat code, but the overloads do only what they need to while all common functionality is in a common function. What is the maintenance overhead? Then "template the send function however that is impossible on an overriden function." why? It is not clear what or why it is impossible

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: *The difficulty comes because the map has to store functions with different signatures because the parameter type is different for every function.* -- Have you tried creating a  base class with an overloaded `operator ()`, then derive classes from it and supply their respective `operator()`?  Then you move the parameters into the class instead of specifying them in the call syntax. When `operator()` is finally called, the class knows what to do since it was prepopulated with the parameters it needs.